# Python subtracting one column from all other in dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with binary variables created using `get_dummy()`. I am using the method `sub()` to subtract one column from all others within this dataframe. However, when i do this, in those cases where i should get a value of -1 I instead get 255 as result.

Does anybody knows why is this and how can i solve it?

Comment: Are you using Pandas? Please add the tag for it, or whatever library you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `pd.get_dummies` returns type of `uint8`, which is not signed. You should convert them before doing subtraction:

```
# ...
df_dummy = pd.get_dummies(your_data).astype(int)
# ...
```

For a quick test, you can compare the results of

```
pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(list('abca')))-1
```

and

```
pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(list('abca'))).astype(int)-1
```